# Binding enum with propertychanged handler not raising converter

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, enums, converters

I'm not new in C# programming with WPF and I've never needed to do this, but now I need it and I'm stuck for some time now with it. I need to bind an enum that has attached it's OnPropertyChanged method to raise a converter every time the enum changes. I've got the following code for the enum:

```
    private WindowState windowstate;
    public enum WindowState
    {
        INITIAL = 0,
        LANGUAGE = 1,
        SENSOR = 2,
        PARAMETERS = 3,
        LEGAL = 4,
        PRIVACY = 5,
        ABOUT = 6,
        MANUAL = 7
    }
    public WindowState State
    {
        get { return windowstate; }
        set { windowstate = value; OnPropertyChanged("State"); }
    }
```

And on the xaml where I bind the enum I've got this:

```
Color="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource ButtonMenuColor}, ConverterParameter=language, ElementName=userControl}"
```

What I want is to change the color of a button depending on the value of the enum. Is it possible to make it this way or WPF, for some reason, does not support this?

This is the converter code:

```
class ButtonMenuColor : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Lynx.Windows.Herramientas.WindowState state = (Lynx.Windows.Herramientas.WindowState)value;
        string param = parameter as string;

        if (state.ToString().ToLower() == param)
            return Application.Current.FindResource("white") as SolidColorBrush;

        return Application.Current.FindResource("buttonmenu_color") as SolidColorBrush;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the convert code?

Comment: Converter code added.

Comment: Have you added a breakpoint to the converter to see if it gets hit or are you just not seeing the colour change?

Comment: Yes, that's why I decided to post this here. I know the converter is not raised because the breakpoint I put inside is never reached.

Comment: It is not reached because there is no State DependencyProperty in the Control of what ever control the x:Name="userControl" is set.

Comment: Gonna try that, thanks.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen that solved my problem!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are binding to a user control, but your property is in a viewmodel?

So change your binding to

```
Color="{Binding DataContext.State, Conv...}"
```

So you are binding to the State property of your userControl's viewmodel. If the State is a DependencyProperty of your userControl the binding should work.

Comment: My property is in a UserControl. This is how I have it declared in the xaml file:
x:Name="userControl"

Comment: The "color" property is in a user control?  Have you set it up as a dependency property?

Comment: Yes, all the properties of the button I'm using are Dependency Properties

Comment: I made State a DependencyProperty and it all started working as expected!

Answer (score 1):

what come into my head are :

> change binding mode to two way.  add updateSourceTrigger =
>   PropertyChanged , NotifySourceUpdated = True
>
> try a fallback value checking your binding is correct or not.
>
> maybe your control loads before your value set.
>
> and put your enum value as 
>   {x:static Namespace:Class.WindowState+LANGUAGE }